# M+ button crashes due to memory format

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

im new to c#

So I've almost finished my calculator and everything works but the program crashes when I start up the program and press the M+ button when "0" is the only number entered into the textbox.

what this button does is adds whatever is in the textbox onto the current memory.  im thinking its because the memory has nothing stored at the time so yea, i just cant figure out how to fix it, correct me if im wrong.

here's the code I have so far.

String memory = "";

```
    private void mDBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = "M+";
        double calcp = double.Parse(memory);
        double calcp2 = calcp + double.Parse(displaytxt.Text);
        memory = calcp2.ToString();

    }
```

Answered. that was quick. thanks :)

Comment: You can't parse an empty string (because 'nothing' is not a valid number). Either set `memory` to `"0"`, or use `TryParse`.

Comment: i thought it was something like this... i just didnt try coz i thought it was too simple lol. thanks it works.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use proper data type for your "memory" field instead of parsing `string` every time: `double` sounds right.

```
 private double memory;
```

Note that you may want to use `double?` is you need to handle special case of "nothing in memory yet" with [HasValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) check:

```
 double? memory;

 ...
 if (memory.HasValue)...
```